# Select wiki page for any DBpedia resource

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I write a simple java code to retrieve Wikipedia page for any DBpedia resource

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    String query = "SELECT ?x WHERE {"
                + "?x foaf:primaryTopic <http://dbpedia.org/resource/France>";
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service, query);
            try{
                ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
                for (; results.hasNext();){
                    QuerySolution sol = (QuerySolution) results.next();
                    String answer = sol.get("?x").toString();
                    System.out.println(answer);

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally{
                qe.close();
            }
```

but I have No results!!
I've tried the sparql query and it works fine so I've no idea what's wrong
[SPARQL Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fx%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fx%20foaf%3AprimaryTopic%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFrance%3E%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)
any suggestions?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the service? JENA? Also, aren't you missing closing `}`?

Comment: yes, I'm using JENA.. and the clothing } is there but still it's not working

Comment: @HananMahmoud I don't see the closing `}` either.  Also, where are the prefix declarations?  I don't see a declaration for `foaf:`.  When you say you're not getting any results, do you mean that the query executes successfully (which would hard to understand, given the syntax errors already noted), or that you get an exception?

Comment: The closing } id in my code but I forgot to write it here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I forgot to put the declaration for foaf
when I correct it, it works just fine. I just edit my query and add the foaf declaration as following:

```
String query = "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"
            + "SELECT  ?x WHERE {" 
                + "?x foaf:primaryTopic <http://dbpedia.org/resource/France>}";
```

Thanks to @joshua-taylor for your point